# How to use subtitles with 360° videos in a-frame?

Tags: aframe

I have 360° Videos playing with a-frame and need to use subtitles to play along. I have the titles in srt format, and don't want to type in every sentence to a new system. I need them to stay in a fixed place on my mobile screen.

I found this: https://github.com/robertogerson/aframe-subtitle
but the example is not working for me.